# Multidimensional Input for Machine Learning

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I have a csv file with data in the the form of:

```
Timestamp,Signal_1,Signal_2,Signal_3,Signal_4,Signal_5
2021-04-13 11:03:13+02:00,3,3,3,12,12
2021-04-13 11:03:14+02:00,3,3,3,12,12
```

Now I want to create a NN to do time series forecasting, so in order to do that I wanted to turn the content into a numpy array so I can assign training/test-sets.
The input aswell as the output should be 5-dimensional (all Signal Groups should be predicted). Currently my code looks like this:

```
import pandas
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from numpy import genfromtxt
filename = 'test.csv'
data = pandas.read_csv(filename , header=0, index_col=0)
my_data = genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',')
print(data.shape)

print(type(my_data))
v, w, x, y, z = my_data
```

I am aware that the actual assignment of the test and training parts is missing, but even in this stage I get the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)`

Comment: my_data variable has NaN values for non-numeric data(header row and timestamp column) which adds up to 6 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly which bit you would like to unpack (looks like you tried to import a version using pandas and one using numpy), but the error is because your `my_data.shape` = `(3, 6)`, as the headers and timestamp column are not interpreted by `np.genfromtxt`, which causes the `too many values to unpack` error at `v, w, x, y, z = my_data`

```py
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  3.,  3.,  3., 12., 12.],
       [nan,  3.,  3.,  3., 12., 12.]])
```

For the numpy `my_data` array, you could index to remove the first row and column and transpose to get it the right way up:

```py
v, w, x, y, z = my_data[1:, 1:].T
```

Which will give you your 1D arrays:

```py
>> v
array([3., 3.])

>> w
array([3., 3.])

>> x
array([3., 3.])

>> y
array([12., 12.])

>> z
array([12., 12.])
```

N.B. Just as an aside, if you try to do the same thing using your pandas dataframe `data`, i.e. `v, w, x, y, z = data`, you'll actually get the column header strings assigned, not the columns themselves. In this case, you want:

```py
v, w, x, y, z = data.values.T
```

If you want the timestamp too, it's probably easier to use the pandas import as it handles mixed data more easily, just reset the index or remove `index_col` from your `read_csv` call:

```py
data = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=0)
u, v, w, x, y, z = df.values.T
```

that will give you your timestamps in `u`.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. Just 2 quick questions. What does the `.T` do? And is there a way for me to also include the timestamp?

Comment: @Zerox the `.T` transposes the rows and columns, because by default, it will try to unpack the two rows into your 5 variables, whereas you want the 5 columns unpacked ;) I'll edit the answer for the timestamp bit

Comment: The pandas solution was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zerox No probs! Glad it helped =)